# Push Pin not locating in bing maps

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, pushpin

The Push Pin tool is not finding the location when I provide the value manually (latitude and longitude).

Here is my code:

```
double dbllat = 13.060407;

double dbllong = 80.249562;

Pushpin mypin = new Pushpin();

watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);

            watcher.MovementThreshold = 40;

            watcher.Start();

            watcher.Position.Location.Latitude = dbllat;

            watcher.Position.Location.Longitude = dbllong;

            mypin .Location.Latitude = dbllat;

            mypin .Location.Longitude = dbllong;

            //CredentialsProvider cp=

            map1.Center = new GeoCoordinate(mypin.Location.Latitude, mypin.Location.Longitude);
            map1.SetView(mypin .Location, 5.0);
            push.Tag = "Location";
            push.Content = "i'm here";
            map1.Children.Add(mypin);
            watcher.Stop();
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Argh, what you need to do? Find current location or display fixed location (13.060407,80.249562) ?

Comment: GeoCoordinateWatcher is async. you need to listen to PositionUpdated.

Answer (score 0):

If thats your error:

**One or more waypoints can't be routed because they are too far from any roads.**

Try

```
GeoCoordinate Loc = new GeoCoordinate(dbllat, dbllong);
mypin.Location = Loc;
```

instead of

```
mypin .Location.Latitude = dbllat;
mypin .Location.Longitude = dbllong;
```